# Can javascript arrays imitate lisp lists ? implementing javascript version of accumulate-n function (SICP exercise 2.36)

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, scheme, sicp

I am implementing javascript version of accumulate-n function (SICP exercise 2.36) 
However unlike scheme, javascript doesn't have nil indicator for arrays, which results in an extra "undefined" value in output array. Should I create a new "List" data structure which imitate Scheme lists or there are some tricks to get this done by native arrays in javascript
Here is the code I am working on

```
const accumulate = (op, init, sequence) => Array.prototype.reduce.call(sequence, op, init)
const map = (fn, sequence) => Array.prototype.map.call(sequence, fn)
const concat = (A, B) => Array.prototype.concat.call([], A, B)
const sum = (a, b) => a + b
const first = (sequence) => {
    const [first, ...rest] = sequence
    return first
}
const rest = (sequence) => {
    const [first, ...rest] = sequence
    return rest;
}
const isEmpty = sequence => sequence.length === 0 
const accumulateN = (op, init, sequenceOfSequences) => {
    if(isEmpty(first(sequenceOfSequences))) return;
    return concat(accumulate(op, init, map(first, sequenceOfSequences)), accumulateN(op, init, map(rest, sequenceOfSequences))) 
}

log(accumulateN(sum, 0, [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [5,6,7]]))           

//outputs [ 10, 13, 16, undefined ]
```

Comment: `(1 2 3) == { car: 1, cdr: { car: 2, cdr { car: 3, cdr: null } } }` ?

Comment: @Sylwester thanks. I had the same idea of emulating List Data structure. However I was trying to get it to work on native arrays

Comment: The problem with using native arrays is that `rest(arr)` twice gives you two different arrays. There will be no sharing between data structures which also makes it very inefficient. With real lists `(cdr lst)` is an O(1) operation that just returns the pointer in second position (first being the car). `[first, ...rest]` is not O(1). It is O(n) at best.